# Numeric Integration of a numerical function

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, interpolation

I am trying to solve this integral numerically:
$$F(s)=\int_{t1}^{s}e^{-B|s-t|}\rho_{12}(t)dt$$
where $t1\leq s\leq t2$ and $\rho_{12}(t)$ is the element of density matrix $\rho(t)$, which can be obtained numerically by solving the Von-Neuman equation $$\dot{\rho}(t)=-i[H(t),\rho(t)]$$ for

$$H_{0}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}h1+v t & -{\it i}g \\{\it i}g & -h1-v t \\\end{pmatrix}.$$

and $t1$ and $t2$ is initial and final times.

It is easy to obtain the density matrix $\rho_{12}$ element by using the code below

```
        g = 1;
        h1 = -50;
        h2 = 50;
        v = 1;
        B = 1;
        t1 = 0;
        t2 = (h2-h1)/v;

H0[t_] = {{h1+v*t , -I*g},{I*g, -h1-v*t }};

        Sol=NDSolveValue[{D[rho[t], t] == -I*(H0[t].rho[t] - rho[t].H0[t]),
                rho[t1] == {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}, rho, {t, t1, t2}];
       
        (*rho12[t]=Sol[t][[1,2]]*)
    
    F[s_]=Integrate[Exp[B*Abs[s-t]]*Sol[t][[1,2]],{t,t1,s}]
```

But my code doesn't work for F(s).
I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me.
Thank you!

Comment: `rho12[t_?NumericQ] := Sol[t][[1, 2]]` and `F[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[B*Abs[s - t]]*rho12[t], {t, t1, s}]`

Comment: Just derive one more differential equation for () (turns out to be ()/=12()−()) and solve simultaneous system of equations for () and ().

Comment: @BobHanlon Notice that $t\le s$ therefore $|s-t|=s-t$

Comment: @yarchik Thank you for your comments